# CTRL+1 Combination not working

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, google-chrome, 22.04

Whenever I try to do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> on Linux it doesn't work. I'm on Chrome and when I try to go to the first tab it doesn't do anything. It works on Windows though. I'm on Kubuntu 22.04.

Comment: It should work according to this > https://linuxhint.com/keyboard_shortcuts_google_chrome/

Comment: @ChanganAuto it happens on all other browsers to, ctrl + 1 just doesnt work

Comment: It works on mine.

Comment: @ChanganAuto it worked on my older computer too but not on this one, like i said it only happens on linux not on windows

Comment: I just tried it using Chrome on Ubuntu 22.04. **It works**. I am going to vote to close this question as the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: @user68186 I found out another program was using it, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since other users claim they can't reproduce your problem, (assuming you're on X11 and not Wayland) this likely happens because another process is claiming your shortcut / hotkey; thus it gets consumed by this other process before it can reach Chrome.

To solve this problem you can read [How do I find out what program 'owns' a hotkey?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261371/how-do-i-find-out-what-program-owns-a-hotkey) to identify what process is claiming the hotkey.

Comment: I have no idea on how to do that, I just have a feeling ibus has something to do with this